# Rasa/Slack Slash command integration issue

Tags: nlp, slack, slack-api, rasa, slack-commands

I have followed the tutorials and successfully set up my bot app through slack. However, this is only when I communicate with the bot directly using the slack app. I want to call my app within a conversation using slash commands. I have provided the redirect url `http://<ngrok_url>/webhooks/slack/webhook` in both the oath permissions and the interactivity sections, as well as the slash command section. Still no luck. In the ngrok session, I get a `500 Internal Server Error`, and in the running rasa session, it shows I have
a `KeyError: payload` issue. How can I integrate the slash commands with my app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate slash commands, you will probably have to create a custom connector based off of the Slack connector, as the slack connector isn't setup to process slash commands.